# How to create summary column from a first column based on values of a second

Tags: r, dplyr

Sorry if that was an unclear way of phrasing the question. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Say I've got a df `data1` that has columns x, y, and z. What I want to do is this: group by x, then create a summary column that's the minimum of y (for each value of x). I.e.,

```
data2 <- data1 %>%
group_by(x) %>%
summarize(min_y = min(y))
```

Then I want to create a second summary column that's the value of z for each minimum y. So for instance, say there are three rows in `data1` where x is 5, and the values of y for those rows are 1, 2, and 3. In those same rows, the z values are, respectively, 6, 5, and 4. What I want to do is have the row in `data2` where x is 5 and y is 1 have z = 6, since that's the z value associated with the minimum value of y for x = 5. I've tried:

```
z_for_miny = z[min(y)]
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `which.min` to find the index of the min value of 'y' and use that to get the corresponding value of 'z'.  If there are ties, this will return only the first instance where the 'y' is min

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>%
         group_by(x) %>%
         summarise(min_y = min(y), z_for_miny = z[which.min(y)])
```

If we have `dplyr` >= 1.0.0, `summarise` can also return more than one row.  So, the ties in `min` value can be filtered with a logical condition `==`

```
data1 %>%
         group_by(x) %>%
         summarise(min_y = min(y), z_for_miny = z[y == min(y)])
```